# PIC18F26K83 LED does not work according to debugger

Tags: c, pic

I am using PIC18F26K83 and I am trying to read temperature value. I use LED as a debug tool. However, it behaves strangely. I have 2 arrays 1 for comparing ADC values and other one is for finding out the temperature from ADC value array. Here is the simplified code that supposed to work:

```
int i;
  int k;
 int temperature;
 unsigned int temp_data;
 int temp_ADC_array[34]= { 259,293,332,377,428,487,555,632,720,821,934,1062,1203,1360,1531,1715,1910,2113,2320,2528,2731,2926,3108,3274,3422,3552,3663,3756,3833,3895,3945,3983,4013,4036};
 int temp_array[34]= {125,120,115,110,105,100,95,90,85,80,75,70,65,60,55,50,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,5,0,-5,-10,-15,-20,-25,-30,-35,-40 };


void main(){
//Set the pins of the MCU
TRISA.B2=0; //LED
LATA.B2=0;


while(1){

   temp_data=2000;

 for(i =0;i<34; i++){
  if(temp_data>temp_ADC_array[33-i]) {
  temperature = temp_array[33-i];
  break;}}

if(temperature>50){
led=1;}
else{
led=0;}

  delay_ms(5000);
}
}
```

In the code above since the temp_data is 2000, from the for loop temperature must be 45. And that is the case in debugger it shows it 45. That means LED must be off because temperature is less than 50 and also in debugger I can see that LED pin is zero all the time. However, when I try it with my circuit LED gets ON. In the other cases when I test LED it works well. Where might be the problem in for loop? Or maybe the problem is in the LED? Thanks beforehand.
Edit: I also tried it with:

```
if(temperature<50){
led=1;}
else{
led=0;}
```

So LED is ON when temperature<50 and also temperature >50 ? How can it be possible?

Note that I use MicroC.

Edit: This is the whole code if anyone interested:

```
#include <stdint.h>
  int i;
  int k;
 int temperature;
 unsigned int temp_data;
 short transmit_data1;
 short transmit_data2;
 uint16_t data_transmit;
 int temp_ADC_array[34]= {  259,293,332,377,428,487,555,632,720,821,934,1062,1203,1360,1531,1715,1910,2113,2320,2528,2731,2926,3108,3274,3422,3552,3663,3756,3833,3895,3945,3983,4013,4036};
 int temp_array[34]= {125,120,115,110,105,100,95,90,85,80,75,70,65,60,55,50,45,40,35,30,25,20,15,10,5,0,-5,-10,-15,-20,-25,-30,-35,-40 };

#define led (LATA.B2)



void Clk_62kHz (){
  NOSC2_BIT =1;
  NOSC1_BIT=1;      //HFINTOSC
  NOSC0_BIT=0;
  FRQ3_BIT =0;
  FRQ2_BIT=0;         //1 MHz
  FRQ1_BIT=0;
  FRQ0_BIT=0;
  NDIV3_BIT =0;
  NDIV2_BIT=1;
  NDIV1_BIT=0;               //Divide 16 =62.5 kHz.
  NDIV0_BIT=0;

  }

void main(){
//Set the pins of the MCU
TRISA.B2=0; //LED
LATA.B2=0;
TRISA.B3=1; //Case Temp A
ANSELA.B3=1;
TRISC.B5=0; //SCLK
TRISC.B6=0; //CS
LATC.B6=1; //Deselect slave
TRISC.B7=0; //DIN
ANSELC.B5=0;
ANSELC.B6=0;
ANSELC.B7=0;
 temperature=0;
    Clk_62kHz();
   //  Clk_8Mhz()  ;
 //PPS Mapping
RC7PPS= 0b00011111 ; //DIN, RC7 = SDIPPS
RC6PPS= 0b00100000; //CS, RC6= SSPPS
RC5PPS= 0b00011110; //SCLK,  RC5=SCKPPS
  //transmit_data= 58112;

transmit_data1=0b11100011;
   //buradan assagisi while loopun icindeydi!!!!!
   LATC.B6=0; //Select the slave


  transmit_data2=0b01111111;





 LATC.B6=1; //deselect the slave && update the data

while(1)
{
    temp_data=2000;
    for(i =0;i<34; i++)
    {
        if (temp_data>temp_ADC_array[33-i])
        {
            temperature = temp_array[33-i];
            if (temperature>50)
            {
                led=1;
            }
            else
            {
                led=0;
            }
        } 
        }
        delay_ms(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first code `led` is always assigned to 0

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Yes, it enters the if statement in the for loop when i=17 and makes temperature =45. Then it goes to if(temperature>50) part and keeps LED OFF. As it should be, but the LED in circuit gets ON when I try. So debugger and the GPIO pin does not match.

Comment: ANSEL register OK?

Comment: @Mike Ansel of the LED Pin?

Comment: Yes you had to switch the led Pin to digital with the ANSEL register

Answer (score 0):

The main loop looks crazy... Try this

```
while(1)
{
    temp_data=2000;
    for(i =0;i<34; i++)
    {
        if (temp_data>temp_ADC_array[33-i]) 
        {
            temperature = temp_array[33-i];
            if (temperature>50)
            {
                led=1;
            }
            else
            {
                led=0;
            }
        }
        delay_ms(5000);
    } 
}
```

and hope you define `led`

Comment: The delay is within the lookup loop.

Answer (score 0):

The test within the loop is wrong.

Your loop, from 'whole code', since it's different than in the 'simplified' code:

```
for(i =0;i<34; i++)
{
    if (temp_data > temp_ADC_array[33-i])   // since temp_ACD_array[0] = 259, 
                                            // this will trigger immediately.
    {
        temperature = temp_array[33-i];     // when you enter the test, 
                                            // temp_ADC_array[33-i] < temp_data
                                            // AND temp_ADC_array[33-(i + 1)] < temp_data
                                            // so temperature is wrong.
        if (temperature>50)
        {
            led=1;    // you turn the LED on, but keep on looping, eventually
                      // you may enter the 'else' part and turn the LED off. 
        }
        else
        {
            led=0;
        }
    } 
    delay_ms(5000);  // I suspect this should not be there, but outside
                     // the lookup loop.
}
```

I know I'm being a bit picky here, but that's what doing embedded stuff does to us...  Isn't the temperature *always* equal to `125 - (5 * i)`? Getting rid of the array `temp_array`would probably make the code easier to reason about.

Also, you want the value of `ì` to indicate where reading is between `temp_ADC_array[33-(i-1)] and temp_ADC_array[33-i]`.  Going down the array of ADC values should correct that.

You also want the LED to trigger once, so the action to turn it on/off should be outside the loop.

```
for (i = 33; i >= 0; --i)  // ADC values going down... stops when i==-1, or 
                          // value in array is less or equal to the reading.
{
     if (temp_ADC_array[i] <= temp_data)
         break;           // we're done getting the temperature index
}

temperature = 125 - (5 * i);  // compute the temp, range is +130° to -40°
                              // an alternative would be to indicate error if i == -1.

led = (temperature > 50); // turn the LED ON or OFF

delay_ms(5000);           // wait, or go on with the rest of the program...
```